# Trouble Configuring Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to recompile the Linux kernel, but before I do this, I need to configure it. I use the following command to try to do this:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- gconfig
```

where `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-` is the prefix of the version of gcc I'm using. Unfortunately, instead of popping up the configuration window, this gives me the message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `gconfig'.  Stop.
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is anyone of  `make xconfig`, `make gconfig` and `make menuconfig` working?

I guess you aren't on the right kernel directory.

Please read this again: [HOWTO compile linux kernel](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-the-Linux-Kernel)

Comment: @John Roberts I think I recall running into this, but I usually put my variables before `make`, so that they are in the environment of the `make` process (not sure it matters). Have you tried what 0x90 posted above?